# Keep children/parent relation in ID's

Tags: rest, security, hash

I have a rest endpoint for example
`/user/{userId}/thread/{threadId}/message/{messageId}`

I have the possibility to create both ID's as I want.

How can I create `threadId` and know the thread is belong to this user,
without checking in database or any service?

Same question, how can I create messageId and keep the information that this message is part of this thread.

I think about hashing `userId` and add the hash as prefix of `threadId`,
and hash `threadId` and put it as prefix in `messageId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answer me [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/236665/way-to-validate-a-parent-child-relation?noredirect=1#comment484199_236665).

The idea is to create an hash that include `threadId` and `userId` and a `salt` to create the `threadId`.

And same idea with `messageId`, will be a hash of `threadId` and `messageId` and a `salt`.